# Working Out The JavaScript Needed To Get A Plus + And Minus - Button Working

Tags: javascript, php, html

Have added a plus + and minus - button to the products page on our website, by changing the following line of code to:

```
$the_button = '<div class="max-qty">' . 
zen_get_products_quantity_min_units_display((int)$_GET['products_id']) . 
        '</div>
            <span class="qty-text">' . PRODUCTS_ORDER_QTY_TEXT . '</span>
            <input type="text" name="cart_quantity" value="' . 
                $products_get_buy_now_qty . 
            '" maxlength="6" size="4" aria-label="' . ARIA_QTY_ADD_TO_CART . '">
            <button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>
            <button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>';
```

The full php code is:

```
<?php
if (CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL == 3 and 
    TEXT_LOGIN_FOR_PRICE_BUTTON_REPLACE_SHOWROOM == '') 
{
    // do nothing
} else {
?>
<?php
    $display_qty = (($flag_show_product_info_in_cart_qty == 1 
                    and $_SESSION['cart']->in_cart($_GET['products_id'])) 
        ? '<p>' . PRODUCTS_ORDER_QTY_TEXT_IN_CART . 
            $_SESSION['cart']->get_quantity($_GET['products_id']) . 
            '</p>' 
        : '');
    
    if ($products_qty_box_status == 0 or 
        $products_quantity_order_max== 1) 
    {
        // hide the quantity box and default to 1
        $the_button = '<input type="hidden" name="cart_quantity" value="1">';
    } else {
        // show the quantity box
        $the_button = '<div class="max-qty">' . 
        zen_get_products_quantity_min_units_display((int)$_GET['products_id']) . 
        '</div>
        <span class="qty-text">' . PRODUCTS_ORDER_QTY_TEXT . '</span>
        <input type="text" name="cart_quantity" value="' . 
            $products_get_buy_now_qty . 
        '" maxlength="6" size="4" aria-label="' . ARIA_QTY_ADD_TO_CART . '">
        <button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>
        <button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>';
    }
    $the_button .= zen_draw_hidden_field('products_id', (int)$_GET['products_id']);
    $the_button .= zen_image_submit(BUTTON_IMAGE_IN_CART, 
                                    BUTTON_IN_CART_ALT, 
                                    ' id="addToCartButton"');
    $display_button = zen_get_buy_now_button($_GET['products_id'], $the_button);
?>
<?php 
    if ($display_qty != '' or $display_button != '') { 
?>
        <div id="cartAdd">
<?php
            echo $display_qty;
            echo $display_button;
?>
        </div>
<?php   
    } // display qty and button ?>
<?php 
} // CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL == 3 
?>
<!--eof Add to Cart Box-->
</div>
</div>
```

Still learning php, and haven't touched on any JavaScript yet. Could do with some help, if anyone knows a way of adding some JavaScript so that the plus + and minus - buttons, if pressed, will increase the default quantity of 1, or decrease, depending on which button is pressed.

Comment: congratulations. That gets the _most unreadable code of the day_ award for the whole month

Comment: unreadable in what respect??????????????

Comment: Well in every respect actually

Comment: It couldn't be any clearer! It's perfectly readable!

Comment: And the normal process here is, first you do some research and have a go at the code. When you have really spent hours on it and got nowhere, you show us the code you have tried and then we have a go at fixing it. Beginners are welcome, but we expect ___some effort from you___ to solve your own problem before asking a question. So show us your best effort. 
___SO is not a free coding service___, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: _It couldn't be any clearer! It's perfectly readable!_ :) :) :) :) :) :) Well now its a bit more perfect and a lot more readable

Comment: I am struggling to understand `if (CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL == 3` as there is no `$` infront of `CUSTOMERS_APPROVAL` it must be a defined value/constant, so why would you be testing it against a value of `3`. Surley you should know if the defined value is 3 or not, it cannot change

Comment: @RiggsFolly everyone has to start somewhere, I used to post questions like that too. It is not cool to ridicule people like that. Granted, it is desired to point any shortcomings and guide how to make things better but ridiculing is just discouraging. If you had a bad day probably best to find something else to do rather than sit on SO.

Comment: @RadixSalvilines yes but you should also take a look at the edit history and OP's original rendering of the code, and what RiggsFolly did to help out with the formatting. The original version was, um, readable, if you like to read for headache and eye strain. To OP: When we ask questions, there's only so much we can do about the content of our code, given we all start somewhere -- however, there's a lot we can do to _format it properly_ to help both ourselves and others easily read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, add it to your website, it is vanilla JS (can be a separate file and then you need this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('.plus').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var qtyInput = document.querySelector('input[name="cart_quantity"]');
        qtyInput.value = parseInt(qtyInput.value, 10) + 1;
    });

    document.querySelector('.minus').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var qtyInput = document.querySelector('input[name="cart_quantity"]');
        qtyInput.value = parseInt(qtyInput.value, 10) - 1;
    });
}
</script>
```

EDIT: Some explanation of what is happening:

- window.onload - this makes your code run when your page has finished loading everything,
- document.querySelector - this is a pointer towards an element, in here we are pointing at the element class `plus`. I would recommend using `id` instead however as classes are most commonly used for styling. When you have a concrete, one element in mind, id's are the best. More here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector.
- addEventListener - JS works on events, you can add various events like onclick, onfocus, onmouseover (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp). First argument is the event name, second is the function to be called when event triggers.
- qtyInput - we assign a pointer to an element to be used in the next line,
- we either decrease or increase the input element value. Call to `parseInt` is optional, it just ensures that what is stored is an integer and not a string.

On the side note I would also recommend separating your PHP code from HTML and JS for readability - it will help you in the future. Meaning assign results of the functions like `get_quantity()` to a variable at the beginning of a file, and then just embed the variable in your HTML.

LAter when you are more confident I would suggest that you have your HTML files completely separate - elements should have their ids like `<div id=some_id"> then add to it JS file that works with those ids and manipulates them separately. This javascript ideally would talk to php to get data and then it updates your HTML with it. Finally once you learn more definitely consider learning how to use modern frameworks like Symfony or Laravel on the backend side and Vue/React/Angular on the frontend side.

Comment: Radix. What an amazing help you've been! I forgot that I had two sets of plus and minus buttons showing (was playing about with the layout of the buttons). Your code works perfectly with the plus and minus buttons, which are displayed on these two lines: echo '<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>';
 echo '<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>'; I don't suppose you know how we could align these buttons, so that they are either side of the quantity input box, which would need adding into this line of code:

Comment: $the_button = '<div class="max-qty">' . zen_get_products_quantity_min_units_display((int)$_GET['products_id']) . '</div><span class="qty-text">' . PRODUCTS_ORDER_QTY_TEXT . '</span><input type="text" name="cart_quantity" id="input" value="' . $products_get_buy_now_qty . '" maxlength="6" size="4" aria-label="' . ARIA_QTY_ADD_TO_CART . '">';

Comment: The other plus and minus buttons code was as the end of the above line of code, but isn't needed anymore, as your code works with the other plus and minus buttons which are echoed in the above.

Comment: You might move the plus button before the input perhaps. For better arrangement you might want to dive into `display` css property https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php - it is a broad topic this one, you might play a little how to make all elements use `display:block` and then make sure the parent element has space to accomodate them. Or even better - take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php which is used in a very popular js library where arranging elements is super easy: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Thanks Radix. Looking into the css as we speak. Appreciate your input / advice.

Comment: HI Radix. Just wanted to say a big thanks for all your help and advise with this. Your code, and all the additional information that you provided, including information about separating code has been very helpful!